# Generate skeleton for aws emr create-cluster command

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, emr

Want to create cluster in aws EMR using cli

`aws emr create-cluster --cli-input-json`

for that i want to generate an input skeleton using following command

`aws emr create-cluster --generate-cli-skeleton`

but it is giving following error-

**`Unknown options: --generate-cli-skeleton`**